# id attributes not working when used to select elements?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, when I use the `id` attributes of `#1700`, `#1800`, `#1900`, and `#today` to target specific elements within my `HTML` document and change their colours they are still **black** rather than being **red** which is what I want them to be. So far everything I have tried in order to change the colours of the targeted elements to **red** is not working.

can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

here is my code:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    
    #1700, #1800, #1900, #today {
     color: Red;
     font-family:anton, sans-serif;
     font-size:38px;
     width: 73px;
    }
    
    #1800 {
     left: 414px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 7px;
      
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <img src="file:///Users/leonvladimirov/Desktop/PM.png" alt=“Menu” style="width: 835px; position: absolute; top: 113px; left: 289px; height: 60px;">
    
    <h2 id=“1700”>1700</h2> 
    <h2 id=“1800”>1800</h2> 
    <h2 id=“1900”>1900</h2> 
    <h2 id=“today”>today</h2>
```

Comment: First thing would be to get rid of those typographic quotes `“` and replace them with regular ones `"`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this, unfortunately, doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: That's why I posted a comment, not an answer.

Comment: changed all of the quotes, no results

Comment: some of the reasons stated by the users who have voted to close this question "_**Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.**_ ". I have now updated the post with adequate question and description, I don't think this question should be closed, at most it would be a good duplicate because **not** knowing what id attributes are valid can be a common problem to many users new to HTML.

Answer (score 5):

> ID attributes must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

so, essentially, your `CSS` is not working because the `id` attributes you've given are **not** valid.

Comment: show your updated CSS within your post, **BUT** don't overwrite the old post, just append the new code below it.

Comment: That didn't fix it.

Comment: @LeonVladimirov check the post, I've just edited it and it's working as expected. but don't forget to change the `id` attribute of `#1800`.

Answer (score 0):

id's can't start with a number, try different id's: https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Answer (score 0):

@Leon Vladimirov - maybe you could rename (if possible) your 1700, 1800, 1900 ID's as something beginning with a letter, that makes contextual sense. Perhaps maybe:

```
<h2 id="century-1700">1700</h2> 
<h2 id="century-1800">1800</h2> 
<h2 id="century-1900">1900</h2> 
<h2 id="today">today</h2>
```

Comment: that fixed it! Thanks, you saved me!!!))

Comment: @Leon Vladimirov - Great to hear! Not a problem :) by chance, would you mind accepting that answer so everyone can see the question is resolved? Thanks!